# what is the most preferrable way to tell people what you studied in a university

Tags: american-english, british-english

so, I have met some guys in my previous schools, and when I asked them what they studied in schools, I got some different ways of responses, and I am wondering whether there are some most acceptable ways, both in American and British Englishs.
Say, I received my Bsc in Biology in 1990 (1987-1990), this is not real, I just make this for the question.
Which of these senteces is the most preferrable?
(1): I was doing Biology from 1987 to 1990 in the University.
(2): My major study was Biology. I was doing it from 1987 to 1990 in the University.
(3): I was studying Biology from 1987 to 1990 in the University
(4): Your answer.
Thank you.
Kitty

Comment: I (AmE) would not use "doing" in this context. Sounds like "doing time in prison" or doing other unrelated activities. I would stick with "studying". If it is just about time spent at the university, you could use "attending". Also optional would be "in/at the university". As for the examples, I think it is mostly a matter of preference or locale which one to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AmE

*If you are talking about a course of study that is complete, use the **simple past*** The combinations are <s>almost</s>? endless:

I studied biology in college.

I studied biology when I was in college.

I majored in biology when I was in college.

*(NOTE in the USA we often say "college" instead of "uiversity," especially when talking in informal or everyday situations, even though we probably attended and graduated from a university.)*

I got a (BS) degree in biology.

I got a (BS) degree in biology from XYZ University.

I earned a (BS) degree in biology (in 1990)(from XYZ University).

I got/earned/received a BS in biology from XYZ University.

I earned/received my BS in Biology in 1990.

I earned/received my Bachelor of Science (degree) in Biology in 1990.

I got/earned/received my BS degree in Biology in 1990 from XYZ University.

I got/earned/received my BS degree in Biology from XYZ University in 1990.

I got/earned/received my Bachelor of Science (degree) in Biology in 1990 from XYZ University.

Note in North America, we normally use BS and not BSc. (Bsc is not correct, as far as I know.)

Answer (score 2):

That's okay.

We can use `'did'` to mean 'study'. If we *believe* user3169, it may not be common in AmE, but it's in BrE and so in InE.

> I did (=study) French at school (in [year])

So, to answer your question...

> I did BSc in Biology at 'x' university in 'y' year.

(Ref: My notes from Swan's PEU).

Comment: @user3169 is correct that in AmE, we don't "do" a degree. We "get" or "receive" or "earn" or "have" a degree, and we say we "studied {X} in college".